# How to get all possible values of the fields TFS API

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to make a utility for working with TFS and I have a question:
how to get all the possible options for the workitem field?

For example I have a field "Assigned to". I need to get all the possible users for this field:
https://gyazo.com/900ac1be671195550e1f8ec6bc619db3

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565296/cannot-get-a-list-of-valid-users-in-tfs-for-assignedto-field-while-creating-new